# Find MAX value per group in SQL pivot

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, max

I have a calculated pivot table consisting of rate names and frequency booked per age group and gender segments, for each rate name:

[image]

I want to find the rate name with the most bookings for each segment, my code so far is:

```
select

/* Rate name */
rt.RateName

/* frequency of rate usage per age group */
,SUM(CASE WHEN res.AgeGroup > 0 AND res.AgeGroup <= 25 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [25 and Under]
,SUM(CASE WHEN res.AgeGroup > 25 AND res.AgeGroup <= 35 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [26-35]
,SUM(CASE WHEN res.AgeGroup > 35 AND res.AgeGroup <= 45 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [36-45]
,SUM(CASE WHEN res.AgeGroup > 45 AND res.AgeGroup <= 55 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [46-55]
,SUM(CASE WHEN res.AgeGroup > 55 AND res.AgeGroup <= 65 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [56-65]
,SUM(CASE WHEN res.AgeGroup > 65 AND res.AgeGroup <= 100 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [66-100]

/* Gender */
,SUM(CASE WHEN res.Gender = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [Male] 
,SUM(CASE WHEN res.Gender = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [Female]
,SUM(CASE WHEN res.Gender = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [No Gender]

FROM reservation res join rate rt on res.RateId = rt.RateId
group by rt.RateName
```

What would be the most optimal way to find the rate names with the biggest number of bookings per group? or should I take a different approach altogether? Any recommendations and suggestions are be highly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use columns.  Aggregate into groups.  However, you need a separate query for each theme.  For ages:

```
WITH r as (
      SELECT rt.RateName
             (CASE WHEN res.AgeGroup > 0 AND res.AgeGroup <= 25 THEN '25 and Under'
                   WHEN res.AgeGroup > 25 AND res.AgeGroup <= 35 THEN '[26-35]'
                   WHEN res.AgeGroup > 35 AND res.AgeGroup <= 45 '[36-45]'
                   WHEN res.AgeGroup > 45 AND res.AgeGroup <= 55 THEN '[46-55]'
                   WHEN res.AgeGroup > 55 AND res.AgeGroup <= 65 THEN '[56-65]'
                   WHEN res.AgeGroup > 65 AND res.AgeGroup <= 100 THEN '[66-100]'
                   ELSE 'OTHER'
             END) as agegrp,
            COUNT(*) as cnt
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY rt.RateName, ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) as seqnum
        FROM reservation res JOIN
             rate rt 
             ON res.RateId = rt.RateId
        GROUP BY rt.RateName
       ) r
SELECT r.*
FROM r
WHERE seqnum = 1;
```

You can use a similar query for genders.

Comment: thanks a lot for the reply, I come from mysql and I have never used this function before but I cannot get it to work properly. The seqnum is always 1, so after the where clause the whole table is returned instead of the max in every group. In order to get it to work in SQLServer 2014 is used this syntax:     ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
    PARTITION BY rt.RateName, res.AgeGroup
    order by rt.RateName
    ) as seqnum

Comment: @Artemis . . . I needed to add the right `ORDER BY` clause.